# Python version in terminal after download Python for OSX

Tags: python-3.x

I downloaded and successfully installed Python 3.3 for OSX. After executing "python" in terminal it opened the python terminal window, stating: "Python 2.7.2 (default, June 20 2012...)

Is there another update I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

python3 should start the correct version for you.